# Unable to ssh into my Jenkins docker instance

Tags: ssh, docker, jenkins

I am trying to use Jenkins Remote CLI to configure my Jenkins server remotely. I am running a jenkinsci/blueocean docker container.

To enabled SSHD on my jenkins server:

1) At http://localhost:8080/configureSecurity/ : Enabled SSHD Port -> Random [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkg4j.png)

2) AT http://localhost:8080/user/baymac/configure: Added my Public key of local machine [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQWme.png)

After detecting the ssh port using this command:

```
curl -D- -o/dev/nul -s http://localhost:8080
```

Trying to ssh from local machine:

```
ssh -l baymac -p 46653 localhost who-am-i
```

Error message:

> ssh: connect to host localhost port 46653: Connection refused

Trying to use Jenkins CLI client to ssh into Jenkins server from local machine:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -ssh -user baymac who-am-i
```

I receive an error message:

> Enter passphrase for /home/parichay/.ssh/id_rsa: Mar 24, 2019 6:38:56
>   AM org.apache.sshd.client.config.hosts.ConfigFileHostEntryResolver
>   reloadHostConfigEntries INFO:
>   resolveEffectiveResolver(baymac@localhost:46653) loaded 1 entries from
>   /home/parichay/.ssh/config org.apache.sshd.common.RuntimeSshException:
>   Failed to get the session.    at
>   org.apache.sshd.client.future.DefaultConnectFuture.getSession(DefaultConnectFuture.java:59)
>     at hudson.cli.SSHCLI.sshConnection(SSHCLI.java:104)     at
>   hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:608)    at
>   hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:427) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
>     at
>   sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
>     at
>   sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
>     at sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:293)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I enter the right passphrase, since I tried to ssh into another device it is working.

Extra information:

I run the docker with the following command:

```
sudo docker run \ 
  --rm \ 
  -u root \ 
  -p 8080:8080 \ 
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \ 
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ 
  -v "$HOME":/home \ 
  --name jenkins \ 
  Jenkinsci/blueocean
```

HTTP auth works:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth baymac:<api_token> who-am-i
```

Message:

> Authenticated as: baymac 
>   Authorities:   authenticated

Inside the docker container bash commandline:

```
docker exec -ti jenkins bash
```

Command 1:

```
bash-4.4# netstat -natp | grep sshd
```

Message"

> "NO_OUTPUT"

Command 2

```
bash-4.4# ps aux | grep sshd
```

Message:

> 2280 root      0:00 grep sshd

I am unable to debug this, a pointer to this error would be really helpful. Some suggestions point me to a direction that `docker run` command should forward the ssh port. I cannot understand how to do it since I chose inside the Jenkins container to run SSH server on random port.

Comment: You may need to supply the `ssh` command with the private key? `-i ~/.ssh/<key_name>`?